# Why MySQL replication process is idle for so long time?

Tags: mysql-replication

Time: 5280463 
    Status: Has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated

Is it okay that mysql replication process is idle for so long time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the type of queries. If you are doing only `select` statements, there will be no change in the data.

You can check the status of the slave using:

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
```

If you find these two lines:

```
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

This means that the replication is working fine. Otherwise, it may be broken due to invalid statement found on the slave machine. Check [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-slave-status.html).

Comment: This works only from command line? I tried this on phpmyadmin database root account sql window, but it didn't write any response other than "Your SQL query has been executed successfully (Query took 0.0008 sec)".

Comment: I did not try it on phpmyadmin. If so, I think you have to execute it on the mysql command line. Don't you have SSH access to your server?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I know of for the master to be idle is that there has been no activity to propagate (or at least no activity written to the binary log). Select statements would have no effect, as they are not written to the binary log. Only inserts, updates and deletes would propagate (as well as DDL).

How long is "long"?

Comment: 5280463 seconds?

Comment: Have you tried doing an insert on the master to see what happens? Also, I'd recommend checking as @Khaled recommended above.